# Why do I get a "Could not chdir to home directory" log after issue "git pull"

Tags: git

I just noticed that when I issue a `git pull` command, I got a `Could not chdir to home directory`. I'm on Mac OSX so I don't have my home directory at `/home/xxxxxx`. Why could this happen? Why does git need to `chdir` to home when doing pull process?

```
$ git pull
Could not chdir to home directory /home/xxxxx: No such file or directory
Current branch mainline is up to date.
```

Comment: Where do you pull from; github, your own server or somewhere else ? Are you using a custom 'git-prompt' ?

Comment: You might be having a git hook. Can you check in your repo for a hook like `$GIT_DIR/.git/hooks/post-update` or some other hook in `.git/hooks/`?

Comment: @PacMan-- I was pulling from our company's repository.

Comment: @mu無 No, `.git/hooks` is empty.

Comment: I suspect that it *could* be the server reporting the problem. I forgot how to test for this, but try checking what message you get, if you log in to the git server using ssh (I'm hoping your company is using gitolite here).

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem.
Login to your repository server:

```
sudo mkdir /home/git
sudo chown git:git /home/git
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that git always chdir to your home directory, in order to read your .git* setup files.
A number of things could be wrong, but you'll most likely be able to find the problem by doing a ...

```
cd your_repository/.git
grep -R '/home' *
```

I believe that would reveal the problematic setting somehow. Try avoiding 'fixing it manually'; instead it would be best to use the revealed information to find out what caused the problem in the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately no `home` found.

Comment: Try, just for experimenting: Temporarily, create a /home folder, set its permission to r-x for everyone. Create a symlink to your own home directory: `sudo mkdir /home; sudo chmod 755 /home; cd /home; sudo ln -s /Users/yourUserName` -Then try the git command again. If the error is not going away, I'm pretty sure it's a problem on the server and not on your local machine.